# Sort a list that contains path in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

How can I sort a path that it contains integer as well as strings? 
My file names are :

```
tmp_1483228800-1485907200_0, 
tmp_1483228800-1485907200_1,
tmp_1483228800-1485907200_2,
....
```

I need to sort them according to the integers after the last underline. 
That’s how my code looks like:

```
act = "." + "/*/raw_results.csv"
files = glob.glob(act)
sorted_list = sorted(files, key = lambda x:int(os.path.splitext(os.path.dirname(x))[0]))
```

I know the problem is there are lot of integers and some strings in between so it can not convert everything to integer,but I do not know how to solve it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your example, you can just sort the names. But I assume that that last number fragment can have more than one digit? Is the part before the number always the same, and how should it be sorted if it's not? Should `a_2` and `b_1` be sorted `a_2, b_1`, or `b_1, a_2`?

Comment: They have more than one digit, up to 4 digits and the part before the number is not same, they vary according to time. I need to perform some functions on the csvs that are within each file, and need to make sure that the files are in the existing order, to know each value that I get from each csv belongs to what tmp file.

Comment: @tobias_k,the main part that is the problem now is to include the os.path.dirname

Comment: How exactly do your `files` look? It seems like `glob` will already include the full path, so your example seems not to be very representative. Will those files have the form `./tmp_1483228800-1485907200_0/raw_results.csv`?

Comment: @tobias_k a full path to one of these files is as follow:"P:\Maryam Nahid\Data_analysis\experiment_180328\data\tmp_1483228800-1485907200_3\raw_results.csv" I guess I am using glob wrongly. The reason I used it is to reach to csvs, but before performing the functions on csvs,I need to put the tmp files in the order that they are already existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comments, your files will be in this format:

```
>>> files = [".../data/tmp_1483228801-1485907200_10/raw_results.csv",
             ".../data/tmp_1483228800-1485907200_1/raw_results.csv",
             ".../data/tmp_1483228801-1485907201_30/raw_results.csv",
             ".../data/tmp_1483228801-1485907200_2/raw_results.csv",
             ".../data/tmp_1483228801-1485907201_9/raw_results.csv"]
```

You can then just extract all the numbers in those full, raw file paths, and convert those to `int`. No need to split the path up into directory path segments.

```
>>> [[int(n) for n in re.findall(r"\d+", f)] for f in files]
[[1483228801, 1485907200, 10],
 [1483228800, 1485907200, 1],
 [1483228801, 1485907201, 30],
 [1483228801, 1485907200, 2],
 [1483228801, 1485907201, 9]]
```

This will extract *all* the numbers in the path and sort by them, giving the highest priority to the first number it finds. If those other numbers are all the same, that's not a problem, and if those are different, it will sort by those, first.

```
>>> sorted(files, key=lambda f: [int(n) for n in re.findall(r"\d+", f)])
['.../data/tmp_1483228800-1485907200_1/raw_results.csv',
 '.../data/tmp_1483228801-1485907200_2/raw_results.csv',
 '.../data/tmp_1483228801-1485907200_10/raw_results.csv',
 '.../data/tmp_1483228801-1485907201_9/raw_results.csv',
 '.../data/tmp_1483228801-1485907201_30/raw_results.csv']
```

If that's not what you want, you can use the (slightly wasteful) `key=lambda f: [int(n) for n in re.findall(r"\d+", f)][-1]` to only sort by the last number.

Comment: Thanks! this helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `str.rsplit()` for the key:

```
>>> lst = ['tmp_1483228800-1485907200_1', 'tmp_1483228800-1485907200_2','tmp_1483228800-1485907200_0']
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x.rsplit('_', 1)[-1]))
['tmp_1483228800-1485907200_0', 'tmp_1483228800-1485907200_1', 'tmp_1483228800-1485907200_2']
```

Comment: it works, yes, but proof not very convincing: the input data is just the same as the output data :) also, how does that float in OP example with `dirname`, `splitext` ... (OP doesn't need splitext for starters)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Agreed, some more test cases would help. I'm assuming the OP has been able to extract the relevant portions of the strings to this point but I might be wrong

Comment: These files are directory names that include each a csv that I need to perform some functions on them. The problem is the code that you wrote does not specify dirname.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I've made a cheap change. Now we see that `sort` works

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre where did you make the changes ?

Comment: in the input data. the items are now unsorted in input.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre one more question, how can I include os.path.dirname ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands looks like my prediction was spot on. You have to add the dirname part.

Answer (score 1):

**code:**

```
import re, os
PATH = "C:\Temp"
lst = ['tmp_1483228800-1485907200_1', 'tmp_1483228800-1485907200_0', 'tmp_1483228800-1485907200_2']

def stringSplitByNumbers(x):
    l = re.findall('\d$', x)[0]
    return [int(y) if y.isdigit() else y for y in l]

print [ os.path.join(PATH, _) for _ in sorted(lst, key=stringSplitByNumbers)]
```

output:

```
['C:\\Temp\\tmp_1483228800-1485907200_0', 'C:\\Temp\\tmp_1483228800-1485907200_1', 'C:\\Temp\\tmp_1483228800-1485907200_2']
```

Comment: Thanks, but your answer does not include the os.path.dirname! That is somthing that is important for me to be included!

Comment: @MaryamNahid Updated it along with path. I hope this works for you.